# Parâmetro não está chegando como null

Tags: java, jsf

Estou trabalhando na internacionalização das minhas mensagens e centralização das mesmas. Eu estou com os seguintes métodos:

```
private static void addMessage(Severity severity, String mensagem, Object...args){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(severity, String.format(get(mensagem, args)), "");
        context.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
    }

    public static void addInfoMessage(String chave, Object...args){
        addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, chave, args);
    }

    public static void addInfoMessage(String chave){
        addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, chave, new Object[]{null});
    }
```

Para tentar reaproveitar código estou tentando passar como `null` o meu array de objetos. Porém no método `addMessage` está chegando um objeto referente a minha classe que chama o `addInfoMessage`. Alguém sabe o porque e como resolvo?

Comment: Se você colocar um `new Exception("Teste").printStackTrace();` no seu método `addMessage`, o que aparece?

Comment: Usando cast fazendo addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, chave, (Object[]) null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está passando `null` no método `addInfoMessage`. Você está passando um array de tamanho 1 onde o primeiro objeto é nulo.

Faça assim se quiser passar null:

```
addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, chave, null);
```

Mas além disso, como o método `addMessage` tem um `vargars` no último parâmetro, você não precisa passar nada e pode fazer assim:

```
addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, chave);
```